# Algoritmo resta de - 97 Javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

¿Alguien sabe por qué se resta el menos - 97? ¿De dónde viene ese número?
Estoy tratando de entender en este algoritmo,

¿Por qué necesariamente tiene que ser el número 97?

```js
var isAnagram = function(s, t) {
    if (s.length !== t.length) return false;
    
    let checkArray = new Array(26).fill(0);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        checkArray[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
    }
    
    for (let x = 0; x < t.length; x++) {
        checkArray[t.charCodeAt(x) - 97]--;
    }
    
    for (let k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
        if (checkArray[k] !== 0) return false;
    }
    
    return true;
    
};

console.log('Anagram: ', isAnagram("anagram","nagaram"))
```

Comment: Que es lo que hace este algoritmo, ubicanos

Comment: isAnagram @Japv, revisa que dos palabras tengan la misma longitud y mismas letras.

Comment: Andres  te invito a hacer el [tour], para que ganes algunas medallas mas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The charCodeAt() method returns an integer between 0 and 65535
> representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.

[String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

En UTF-16 la *a* se representa con el código 97, así sucesivamente, la *z* con 122.
Quizás para el alfabeto en español es más complicado, pues la *ñ* es el código 241. Realmente no lo he pensado.

En fin, el -97 deja un rango (nueva codificación) desde 0 a 25 (el número de letras en el alfabeto inglés). Básicamente lo que se busca es un equivalente numérico para cada letra del alfabeto, y partiendo de 0 (para facilitar el trabajo con los índices en `checkArray`).

Comment: Gracias @eniel.rod

Comment: @Andres con gusto!

Answer (score 1):

El 97 hace referencia al Código ASCII, cuyo 97° carácter es la "a" minúscula, sin embargo yo no utilizaría ese algoritmo puesto que es un poco torpe y no funcionaría para todos los casos.

Uno de los mejores algoritmos que hay es:

En una cadena de texto de n caracteres comparar el carácter i con el carácter n-i (la primera con la última, la segunda con la penúltima, ...), en caso de que no coincidan las letras comparadas se sabe que ya no es un anagrama y se termina de iterar la cadena de texto una vez que se alcanza la mitad de la palabra.

Creo que tiene una complejidad lineal de Máximo O(n/2) y Mínima de O(1)

Comment: Gracias @Eduardo